# Method 'Sockets.Plugin.Abstractions.ITcpSocketClient.ConnectAsync' not found (Neo4j driver)

Tags: .net, xamarin, neo4j

I am trying to use the **Neo4j .Net driver** to communicate with my **local Neo4j database**, from within a **Xamarin** application.

This is my code:

```
using Neo4j.Driver.V1; // I have this at the top of the class

//and this in the constructor just to test it
using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "root")))
using (var session = driver.Session())
{
    session.Run("CREATE (a:User {name:'Arthur'})");
}
```

It is essentially the same code they give as an example on their website (https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/).

When I try to run the project I get the following error:

[image]

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Sockets.Plugin.Abstractions.ITcpSocketClient.ConnectAsync' not found.
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.SocketClient.Start () [0x00023] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.SocketConnection.<.ctor>b__3_0 () [0x00000] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2157
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00052] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3189
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3054
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.SocketConnection..ctor (Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.ISocketClient socketClient, Neo4j.Driver.V1.IAuthToken authToken, Neo4j.Driver.V1.ILogger logger, Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Messaging.IMessageResponseHandler messageResponseHandler) [0x00046] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.SocketConnection..ctor (System.Uri url, Neo4j.Driver.V1.IAuthToken authToken, Neo4j.Driver.V1.Config config) [0x00016] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Session..ctor (System.Uri uri, Neo4j.Driver.V1.IAuthToken authToken, Neo4j.Driver.V1.Config config, Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.IConnection conn, System.Action`1[T] releaseAction) [0x0005c] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.SessionPool.<GetSession>b__14_0 () [0x0003b] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
  at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.LoggerBase.TryExecute[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] func) [0x00000] in <d05dc2e6bd2a40acab42430b347d4724>:0
```

I tried looking through the Neo4j manual (http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/) and searching online, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the latest Neo4J Driver:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver/1.0.2

You'll see it has a dependency on rda.SocketsForPCL (>= 1.2.2)

The method Neo4J is trying to call is modified in the latest rda.SocketsForPCL:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/rda.SocketsForPCL/2.0.2

The developer's comment is:

> `TcpSocketClient`'s `ConnectAsync` method optionally takes a
>   `CancellationToken` to support client-invoked cancellation and
>   scenarios like timeout. Thanks @SparkStream

Your error is:

> Method 'Sockets.Plugin.Abstractions.ITcpSocketClient.ConnectAsync' not
>   found.

***Solution is:***

Choose an earlier version of rda.SocketsForPCL (such as 1.2.2, which definitely works) and your problem will go away.

For example, if you're using the paket dependency manager for NuGet, you can add the following to your *paket.dependencies* file:

```
nuget rda.SocketsForPCL ~> 1
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I then just needed to change "bolt://localhost" to "bolt://127.0.0.1:7687" for everything to work perfectly